# Infinispan invalidation cache invalidates on new key

Tags: infinispan, cache-invalidation

We have a two active/active node Wildfly 19 cluster configuration with infinispan (v 9.4.18) invalidation cache.

```
<invalidation-cache name="opencell-tenant-cache">
    <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="NONE"/>
</invalidation-cache>
```

According to the infinispan documentation, when a cached value change on node1, a InvalidateCommand is send from node 1 to node2, invalidating/removing a key entry from a node2 cache.

What I noticed is that InvalidateCommand is send even on a new key put.

In our application if key is not found in cache, a value will be loaded from a DB and put in a cache. And as both servers are active, I get the following never ending scenario:

Request to Node 1 > Key not found on Node1 cache > Value is loaded from DB and put to Node1 cache > key invalidated on Node2
Request to Node 2 > Key not found on Node2 cache > Value is loaded from DB and put to Node2 cache > key invalidated on Node 1
Request to Node 1 > Key not found on Node1 cache > Value is loaded from DB and put to Node1 cache > key invalidated on Node 2
and so on.

With this scenario, I am invalidating cache constantly, even though data is never changed.
I would expect that no invalidation command is send on new key put.

Otherwise what is a practical use of invalidation cache, if same key put after receiving invalidation command will trigger an invalidation again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`I would expect that no invalidation command is send on new key put.`
And what is a new put?

`Request to Node 2 > Key not found on Node2 cache` <- in your example, Node 2 does not have the key locally; so it is a new put.

Node 2 can fetch the key from Node 2 if you configure a `ClusterLoader`. See [Invalidation Cache Mode Documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#invalidation-caches_clustered-caches).

If invalidation does not fit your data access, take a look at the other cache modes (like replicated/distributed).

Comment: It seems that one need to use Cache.putForExternalRead() when putting a new key to an invalidation cache, so it would not trigger invalidation on other nodes.

I would expect that infinispan itself would do such logic :
<pre>
    If (cache.containsKey(A){
      cache.put(A,B); // sends invalidation
    } else {
      cache.putForExternalRead(A,B); // does not send invalidation
    }
</pre>
However JPA use invalidation cache for entity L2 cache. And even I dont change any data in DB (all read operations), everytime I change a server, I see invalidation requests between the servers.

Comment: > I would expect that infinispan itself would do such logic : <pre> If
> (cache.containsKey(A){ cache.put(A,B); // sends invalidation } else {
> cache.putForExternalRead(A,B); // does not send invalidation } </pre>

This would be more expensive than just invalidating on every put, since containsKey(...) would need to be broadcast, and, if transactional, atomic.

Comment: 1. **Cache.putForExternalRead(A,B);** isn't always an option (if you use it as Spring cache for example).
2. **ClusterLoader** is deprecated and going to be removed https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-11863 https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-11864

Comment: And **Replicated** mode (probably the best alternative) introduces serialization (performance penalty) that can't be avoided even for local gets it seems.